# Correct redirect_uri for Google Sheet (not web app)?

Tags: javascript, oauth2, redirect, google

We have several Google Sheets that interact with Salesforce, all now broken with ouath1 deprecation. I've found lots of examples of oauth2 for web apps, but I can't make it work with a Google sheet. I think my problem is an incorrect callback uri. Does anyone have a working example? Here's my code:

```
var url = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize";
var payload = {
  'response_type':'code',
  'client_id':sfConsumerKey,
  'scope':'full',
  'redirect_uri':'https://script.google.com/macros/'
};
var options = {
  'method':'post',
  'payload':payload
};
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

I get an error at this point:

```
redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=redirect_uri must match configuration
```

This code is in a library. Each user will have their own copy of a spreadsheet that uses the library.

Comment: whats the call back URL configured in SFDC connected apps?

Comment: I don't know, but I'd expect that it's app-specific. I don't know what the right URL is for a Google spreadsheet. It may be even worse in my case. Users make their own copies of the sheet, so it might be the case that the URL isn't known until run time. Google provides an API call that returns the URL of a what they call a web app: `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()`. Doesn't work in the case of script in a spreadsheet.

Comment: Google must be going to one specific URL and then redirecting .The mismatch is because your redirect URL that you have provided is not matching with callback url in your connected app

Comment: I'm not sure what 'connected app' means in this case. All I have is the spreadsheet that's trying to access Salesforce. I need to know how to find the callback URL is for a Google spreadsheet. I tried `https://script.google.com/macros/` from another example, but that doesn't seem to work.